# magento 2.4.3 admin order grid not showing

Tags: order-grid, magento2.4.3

I installed my custom plugin in Magento 2.4, but after that I'm not able to see the order list in the grid. Here below a screenshot:
[image: admin order list]

My plugin adds three columns in sales_order_grid, here below I'll report the code for the first one as a sample

Vendor/App/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top"/>  <!-- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5408 -->
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        
        <column name="create_invoice" class="Vendor\App\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ColumnCreateInvoice">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Crea fattura</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">600</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_App/js/grid/columns/create_invoice</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
            [... the other two columns]
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Vendor/App/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/create_invoice.js:

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column',
    'jquery',
    'mage/template',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'ko',
], function (Column, $, mageTemplate, sendmailPreviewTemplate, ko) {
    'use strict';
 
    return Column.extend({
        defaults: {
            bodyTmpl: 'ui/grid/cells/html',
            fieldClass: {
                'data-grid-html-cell': true
            }
        },
        
        getUrl: function (row) {
            return row[this.index+'_Url'];
        },
        getOrderId: function (row) {
            return row[this.index + '_orderId'];
        },
        getLabel: function (row) {
            return row[this.index + '_html']
        },
 
        preview: function (row)
        {
            $.post(this.getUrl(row)).then(function(response)
            {
                if(response.descriptionResponse)
                    alert(response.descriptionResponse);
            })
        },
        
        getFieldHandler: function (row)
        {
            return this.preview.bind(this, row);
        }
    });
});
```

Vendor/App/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/ColumnCreateInvoice.php:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\App\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
 
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

class ColumnCreateInvoice extends Column
{
    protected $objectManager;
    protected $orderRepository;
    
    public function __construct
    (
        ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Vendor\App\Helper\Data $helper,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }
    
    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items']))
        {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item)
            {
                $order  = $this->orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $orderId = $order->getId();
                isset($order)? $incrementId = $order->getIncrementId() : $incrementId = $document->getIncrementId();
                
                // uso il nuovo metodo per recuperare il numero del documento nel gestionale Vendor (registrato nella tabella)
                $docNumber = $this->helper->getF24DocNumber($incrementId); 
                
                // Costruisco l'url associato al controller CreateInvoice
                $baseUrl = $this->objectManager
                    ->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                    ->getStore()
                    ->getBaseUrl();
                $url = $baseUrl. "vendor/index/createinvoice/id/". $incrementId;

                if($order->isCanceled())
                    $item[$fieldName . '_html'] = "<center>Ordine cancellato</center>";
                else
                {
                    $invoicesIds = $this->helper->getInvoicesIds($incrementId);
                    if(!$invoicesIds)
                        $numberInvoices = 0;
                    else
                        $numberInvoices = count($invoicesIds);
                    if($order->canInvoice() || ($order->hasInvoices() > $numberInvoices))
                        $item[$fieldName . '_html'] = "<center><button class='button' title='Crea la fattura sul server di Vendor'><span>Crea fattura</span></button></center>";
                    else
                        //se lo trovo riporto il riferimento al numero della fattura in F24
                        $item[$fieldName . '_html'] = !empty($docNumber)? "<center><b>Ordine fatturato<br><br> Numero doc in Vendor: " . $docNumber . "</b>" : "<center><b>Ordine fatturato</b></center>";
                }

                $item[$fieldName . '_orderId'] = $orderId;
                $item[$fieldName.'_Url'] = $url;
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

I tried to replace the path in sales_order_grid.xml with `Vendor/App/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/` but no change also after bin/magento setup:upgrade and bin/magento setup:di:compile

If I remove my plugin from the environment an then run setup:upgrade and setup:di:compile the admin order grid displays correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the system throws `\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException` in one of your custom logic

Try to add `try {} catch(\Exception $e) {}` into `ColumnCreateInvoice:: prepareDataSource` when you work with repository

Comment: I added try/catch as you suggested and that resolved! Now I'm able to see the grid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are no any field named `create_invoice` in `sales_order_grid` table.

Change this line with any of field already exist in that table or create `create_invoice` field in `sales_order_grid` table.

```
<column name="create_invoice" class="Vendor\App\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ColumnCreateInvoice">
```